# WordPress 6.0 and _s theme posts and pages are not found

Tags: wordpress, underscores-wp, wordpress-6

The automatic update for WordPress to 6.0 caused issue that none of the content is displayed now. All pages, posts etc are showing "not found" as posts and pages don't exist anymore. It works fine when reverting to 5.9. Here's my index.php of the theme for it:

```
    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :

        if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
            ?>
            <header>
                <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>
            <?php
        endif;

        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            /*
             * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

        endwhile;

        the_posts_navigation();

    else :

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>

</main><!-- #main -->
```

Have there been major updates in 6.0 that templates don't work or post query has changed?

Answer (score 1):

It was conflict with the plugin Filter Everything Pro

Comment: Many thanks. You saved my day. Do you know that's fixed?

Comment: I found it has a new version that fixed the conflict.